# FlowLayoutPanel autosize

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, flowlayoutpanel

I have flow layout panel dock (Fill) in parent container. The Parent container DockStyle is set to Top.  Also I set the FlowDirection property to LeftToRight for flow layout panel and the AutoSize property to True for both containers. The main function of flow layout panel is to keep dynamically added buttons.

The Code for creating Buttons

```
Button productButton = new Button();
productButton.AutoSize = true;
productButton.AutoEllipsis = false;
productButtonPanel.Controls.Add(productButton);
```

There is enough space to keep 10-12 buttons in one line and the FlowLayoutPanel  is doing great. It keeps all new buttons in one line.
The problem is that the FlowLayoutPanel  resizes (vertically) every time I add new Button even when the extra space ("New button line") is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i solved the problem. Flow Layout Panel was docked in Table Layout Panel ?
It seems that Table Layout Panel is talking control over autosizing  of child Flow Layout Panel.
The workaround of this problem is:

```
Table Layout Panel (autosize = true)
    Panel (autosize = true, Dock=Fill)
        Table Layout Panel  (autosize = true, Dock=Fill)
```

More details:
[FlowLayoutPanel Height bug when using AutoSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647244/flowlayoutpanel-height-bug-when-using-autosize)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;` will solve your problem. E.g.

```
        Form f = new Form();
        Panel parent = new Panel { Dock = DockStyle.Top, BackColor = Color.Blue, AutoSize = true  };

        FlowLayoutPanel p1 = new FlowLayoutPanel { FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.LeftToRight };
        p1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        p1.AutoSize = true;
        p1.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;

        Button b1 = new Button { Text = "Button1", AutoSize = true, AutoEllipsis = false };
        p1.Controls.Add(b1);
        b1.Click += delegate {
            Button b2 = new Button { Text = "Button" + (p1.Controls.Count + 1), AutoSize = true, AutoEllipsis = false };
            p1.Controls.Add(b2);
        };
        parent.Controls.Add(p1);
        f.Controls.Add(parent);
        Application.Run(f);
```